# How can I deserialize child elements in a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

I'm returning the data I got from the db as follows.

I can get the BusPersonals values as follows.
How can I handle this in the shortest way? Because I have too many fields in BusPersonals.
I don't want to get all the values one by one with `Select`. Can I handle this without using autoMapper?

```
public Task<BusApiDto> DetailBus(int id)
{
var firstTable = dbContext.Bus.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
var secondTable = dbContext.BusPersonals.Where(x => x.BusId == id).ToListAsync();

//The `firstTable` is for example as follows
BusName : "Yellow Bus",
BusVehicle: "07506",

// The `secondTable` is for example as follows
FirstName = "Jack",
LastName = "Jrs",
BestColors = ["Red", "Blue", "Black"]
Foods = [{"Allergy": false, "Food": "Fish"}, {"Allergy": false, "Food": "Beef"}, 
{"Allergy": true, "Food": "Nuts"}

FirstName = "John",
LastName = "Travolta",
BestColors = ["Pink", "Blue", "Black"]
Foods = [{"Allergy": true, "Food": "Fish"}, {"Allergy": false, "Food": "Beef"}, 
{"Allergy": true, "Food": "Nuts"}

    BusApiDto busApiDto = new BusApiDto ()
    {
     BusName = firstTable.BusName;        
     BusVehicle = firstTable.BusVehicle;
     BusPersonals = secondTable.Select(x => new PersonalApiDto()
         FirstName = x.FirstName,
         LastName = x.LastName,
         BestColors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(x.BestColors),
         Foods = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FoodsApiDto>>(x.Foods),
     {
     }).ToList();
   };
return busApiDto;
 }
    // BusApiDto
    public string BusName { get; set; }
    public string BusVehicle { get; set; }
    public List<BusPersonalApiDto> BusPersonals{ get; set; }

    // PersonalApiDto
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<string> BestColors { get; set; }
    public List<FoodsApiDto> Foods { get; set; }

    // FoodsApiDto
    public bool Allergy { get; set; }
    public string Food { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is `id`? You use it twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstTable = dbContext.Bus.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
var secondTable = dbContext.BusPersonals.Where(x => x.BusId == id).ToListAsync();

List<BusPersonalApiDto> personels = new List<BusPersonalApiDto>();
foreach(var personel in secondtable)
{       
   List<FoodsApiDto> foods = new List<FoodsApiDto>();
   foreach(var food in personel.Foods)
   {
     foods.add(new FoodsApiDto(){
        Allergy = food.Allergy,
        Food = food.Food
     });
   }
   personels.add(new BusPersonalApiDto{
      FirstName = person.FirstName,
      LastName = person.LastName,
      Foods = foods
   });
   
}
BusApiDto busApiDto = new BusApiDto(){
  BusName = firstTable.BusName,
  BusVehicle = firsTable.BusVehicle,
  BusPersonals = personels
};
return busApiDto;
```